# How to provoke an error in my program to display the printstacktrace

Tags: java, printstacktrace

How do I provoke an error so that the `exc.printStackTrace(System.out);` is displayed when I run the program:

```
public String getName(){
    try {
        if(haveName()) return Name;
        else {
            throw new CorrectNameException("no name");
        }
    } catch (ExistException e) {
        return e.getExc();
    } catch (CorrectNameException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
        return "nameless";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: nothing's wrong, my professor asked me to provoke an error in my program so that the stacktrace from the attached program is printed on the console when the program is executed

Comment: You need to understand your own code. The stack trace is printed when a CorrectNameException is caught. Such an exception is thrown and then caught if the else block is executed. The else block is executed if `haveName()` returns false. So, for the stack trace to be printed, haveName() must return false. You haven't posted its code, so we don't know when it returns false and when it returns true. Read its code, and make logical deductions.

Comment: Although there is some sort of entertaining irony in that, the name `CorrectNameException` makes me shudder. Sounds like an `EverythingIsFineException`, and the usual case is that everything is *not* fine... However, just a remark: In the pain of debugging, I consider it as legitimate to occasionally throw in a `new Exception().printStackTrace()` **any**where in the code, just to see where the call came from (although usually, a debugger shows you that, when you add a breakpoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `haveName()` return false. Simple.

Comment: well i'm not too smart, how do i do that? like this " if(haveName()) return false;"

Comment: `public boolean haveName(){return false;}`?

Answer (score 0):

According to what you posted in question, answer would be **"When *haveName()* method returns false"**

But If you explain complete use case, we can rectify your code a little bit. As per my understanding your method is checking two things.

- Name exist or not?
- Name is valid or not?

So I have couple of question regarding your query:

- Does method **haveName()** check for existence and validity both? (or only for existence).
- Are you throwing any exception inside **haveName()** method?